# PCRE Mutiple string regex negation

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

PCRE Regex - negated set

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong to get this regex string negated in my match?

```
^.+ temp duration: \d\d:\d\d:\d\d:\d\d - (\d+\.\d).*
```

In my blob of text there's multiple capture groups of `(\d+\.\d)` the above regex seems to match EVERYTHING in the blob with a capture group for only the last match --- but what I want is everything but the `(\d+\.\d)` groups to match...

example blob:

> details temp duration: 00:00:05:24 - 6.0 temp duration: 01:41:28:24 -
> 6089.0 temp duration: 00:00:09:24 - 10.0 Total

UPDATE 2:
this seems a bit better but still not working

```
([\s\S]*?)temp duration: \d\d:\d\d:\d\d:\d\d - (\d+\.\d)
```

Comment: Could you also add some samples of that blob?

Comment: Do you want to say you want to execute a single regex match operation and get `abc temp duration: 12:23:45:64 -  abc` out of `abc temp duration: 12:23:45:64 - 234.1 abc`?

Comment: also FWIW this captures the values I need just need the inverse of this ```(?=[\s\S]*?)temp duration: \d\d:\d\d:\d\d:\d\d - (\d+\.\d)```

Comment: So you want to capture only `Total` from the above blob example?

Comment: I want to match everything but 10.0, 6.0, 6089.0 ... right now it only matches those

Answer (score 0):

You should either replace the matched value with an empty string or capture only the needed part and get the captured group value. But in the case when from string `temp duration: 00:00:09:24 - 10.0 Total` should match `temp duration: 00:00:09:24 -  Total`, then it is suitable to replace.
This regex matches all in expected format till the number and will not include the things after the `(?=\d+\.\d)`. See the regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/f87Y1b/1).

```
^[\s\S]*?temp duration: \d\d:\d\d:\d\d:\d\d - (?=\d+\.\d)
```

The `(?=` is a [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that asserts the existence but does not capture.

Answer (score 0):

You can not get 2 dissected parts as one whole match using a regex.

Using PCRE as in the title, you might use a SKIP FAIL approach and get separate matches:

```
\h+\d+\.\d+\b(*SKIP)(*F)|.+?(?=\h+\d+\.\d+\b|$)
```

**Explanation**

- `\h+` Match 1+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `\d+\.\d+\b` Match 1+ digits, a dot and 1+ digits followed by a word boundary
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` Skip the match
- `|` Or
- `.+?` Match 1+ chars, as least as possible (Or use .*?) to als match empty strings)
- `(?=` Positive lookahead to assert what is to the right is:

  - `\h+\d+\.\d+\b` The matching pattern
  - `|` Or
  - `$` Assert the end of the string (to match the last part if present)
- `)` Close the lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y78YKR/1)

Another idea might be to use the match only (you don't have to use a capture group here), and replace with an empty string:

```
\h+\d+\.\d+\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/o25r0e/1)